# Save model field value as default for another field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here's a relevant code from my `models.py` file

```
class PhotoManager(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     def model_instance_id(self):
         return self.id
     index = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = model_instance_id, blank=True, unique = False)
```

What I'm trying to do is to save `model id` field value into index field (to safely edit it later with AJAX calls to Django Rest Framework). As I understand, the only correct option to save model field value to another field is setting default value as a function. When I save model instance I get an error:

> TypeError: model_instance_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Anyway, I can't figure out, how to reference ID field in mentioned function.

I tried use save method, but it just does nothing

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if not self.index:
         self.index = self.id
     super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you **set the `index` before saving the instance**, at that point, new model instance do not yet have an `id`. So you can perform two `.save()`s: one before obtaining the `id`, and one to `save` the new index.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.id is None:
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.index is None:
        self.index = self.id
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But that being said, it is still not a good idea: there are various ways to circumvent the `.save(..)` method, for example when updating specific fields, etc.

Therefore I advice you to make a column `_index` instead that is `NULL`-able, and then write a `@property` to handle the case where the `index` is `NULL`:

```
class PhotoManager(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    _index = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=None, blank=True)

    @property
    def index(self):
        if self._index is not None:
            return self._index
        return self.id
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually solved my issue!
However, I don't have now a special form field on Django Rest Framework view page and now have to figure out, how to PATCH it after saving model instance, but that's another issue

Answer (score 0):

You should use parentheses, when calling function

```
index = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = model_instance_id(), blank=True, unique = False)
```

Comment: It  did not work- when I've added parenthesis, I got the same error at the process of making migrations